# Stitching arrays together in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is there an easy way to stitch together arrays in numpy, such that the first term in one array adds with the third term in another array? For example:

```
a = np.array((1,2,3))
b = np.array((2,3,4))
```

I would like the result to be (1,2,5,3,4) in this case. I can do this with for loops, but I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this using numpy as well. Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to do this for only `a` and `b` or do you have more arrays?

Comment: Quick 'n dirty solution: `np.concatenate((a[:-1], [a[-1] + b[0]], b[1:]))`

Comment: I have a variable amount of arrays that I would like to stitch together, such that their results add together in this way

Comment: Are the arrays of variable length?

Comment: Are the numbers in the overlapping portion of the arrays always the same? If not how do you specify which one 'wins'?

Comment: Each array is always the same length, and since the numbers in the overlapping region are always added together, it's not important which one 'wins'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

For a pair of every two arrays, you could do the following.

```py
np.hstack([a[:-1], np.array([a[-1], b[0]]).sum(), b[1:]])
```

> ## For a list of arrays:
>
> The dummy data that I used here has been created with code given at the end (bottom-most-section) of this solution. You only need the following two functions for this.

```py
def array_stitch(a, b):
    c = np.hstack([a[:-1], np.array([a[-1], b[0]]).sum(), b[1:]]) 
    return c

def recursive_array_stitch(array_list):
    c = array_stitch(array_list[0], array_list[1])
    for e in array_list[2:]:
        c = array_stitch(c, e)
    return c

recursive_array_stitch(array_list)
```

**Output**:

```
array([ 4,  5,  6,  8,  2,  3,  8,  5,  9,  4,  5,  6,  8,  5,  4,  5,  6,
       10,  2])
```

Here the `array_list` is given by:

```
[array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([4, 5, 6]),
 array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([1, 2]),
 array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([2]),
 array([1, 2])]
```

> ### Detailed Solution
>
> For two arrays only, as shown in the question's problem statement. For multiple arrays, this could be used recursively and that is what has been done in the section above.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2,3))
b = np.array((2,3,4))
c = np.hstack([a[:-1], np.array([a[-1], b[0]]).sum(), b[1:]]) 
c
```

**Output**:

```
array([1, 2, 5, 3, 4])
```

If you want it as a tuple: `c.tuple()` will give you `(1, 2, 5, 3, 4)`.

### For A list of Arrays

See the solution at the beginning for a list of arrays. I will use the data created using the following code.

```py
# Dummy Data
np.random.seed = 43
start, stop = np.random.randint(1,5,size=8), np.random.randint(3,9,size=8)
array_list = [np.arange(k,k+3) if l<=k else np.arange(k,l) for k,l in zip(start, stop)]
array_list
```

**Output**:

```
[array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([4, 5, 6]),
 array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([1, 2]),
 array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([2]),
 array([1, 2])]
```

Comment: Based on the OP's comment: _I have a variable amount of arrays_, `numpy.hstack` would be hard to generalize

Comment: @Chris Thank for pointing it out. Will update the solution accordingly.

Comment: @Chris Generalized solution is posted with `numpy.hstack` and variable number of arrays.

Comment: @JesseBluestein Please consider **voting up** as well. Thank you selecting it as the **accepted** answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sum only the last and first items of consecutive arrays:

```
def stitch(arrs, dtype=None):
    if len(arrs) < 2:
        raise ValueError("Not supported")
    res = np.empty(sum(x.size - 1 for x in arrs) + 1, dtype=dtype)
    idx = 0
    res[0] = arrs[0][0]
    for i in range(len(arrs) - 1):
        a, b = arrs[i], arrs[i + 1]
        off = a.size - 1
        res[idx+1:idx+off] = a[1:-1]
        res[idx+off] = a[-1] + b[0]
        idx += off
    res[idx+1:] = arrs[-1][1:]
    return res
```

Unlike the other answers, this one avoids unnecessary list-conversions/copies and additions. :) Note that @Torben's answer might still be faster for arrays of sufficiently small size.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a simple way, since this does not seem a common operation.

If you have a known list of inputs, I would recommend to preallocate the result and then use inplace-addition with a moving slice:

```
def stitch(list_of_arrays):
    final_size = sum(len(arr) for arr in list_of_arrays) - len(list_of_arrays) + 1
    out = np.zeros(final_size)
    ofs = 0
    for arr in list_of_arrays:
        out[ofs:ofs+len(arr)] += arr
        ofs += len(arr) - 1
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `functools.reduce`:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

def f(arr1, arr2):
    return [*arr1[:-1], arr1[-1] + arr2[0], *arr2[1:]]

a = np.array((1,2,3))
b = np.array((2,3,4))
c = np.array((10,20,30))

reduce(f, [a,b,c])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 5, 3, 14, 20, 30]
```